# Dispatch queue blocks main thread

Tags: ios, swift

I have multiple tasks that I want to put in a serial/concurrent queue running in background thread. Each of the tasks will `fetch` data from api(async) then `copyItem`(sync, depends on the res of `fetch`). The code below blocks main thread. However main thread will not be blocked if I only assign copyItem to the queue. Why can't I run the whole block in background thread ?

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue", qos: .background)
tableView.selectedRowIndexes.forEach { row in

  serialQueue.async {   

    InitData.fetch("someUrl") { initData in
      let fileManager = FileManager()                
      do {
         try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: "pathA", toPath: "pathB")
      } catch let error {
         print(error)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't block main thread:

```
tableView.selectedRowIndexes.forEach { row in

  InitData.fetch("someUrl") { initData in
    let fileManager = FileManager()
    let workItem = DispatchWorkItem {          
      do {
        try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: "pathA", toPath: "pathB")
      } catch let error {
        print(error)
      }
    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(execute: workItem)
  }
}
```

Comment: if in your first code block you may call `print(Thread.current.isMainThread)` just before calling: `copyItem`

Comment: it returns true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can deduce from your symptoms that `InitData.fetch` takes two arguments: a string (`"someUrl"`) and a callback, and that it submits the callback to **the main queue** for execution. It  doesn't matter what queue you were on when you called `InitData.fetch`. What matters is the queue that `InitData` eventually (asynchronously) uses to schedule execution of the callback. Maybe you can tell it which queue you want it to use, but apparently in the program you've written, it uses the main queue.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to run `fetch -> copyItem` in background If `InitData.fetch` has to be async ?

Comment: @vincentf in your solution with `DispatchWorkItem`, if you notice, you are already doing this